# Crop file name after extension, using PHP

Tags: php

I have a slightly corrupt image URL and I'd like to use PHP to crop it after the file extension to make it display correctly.

How do I change this:

`http://localhost:8888/wordpress/content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-c6f73a1461e90382eb2f9f633b224c1a/2014/11/0065B3.png|:||:||:||:|188`

to this:

`http://localhost:8888/wordpress/content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-c6f73a1461e90382eb2f9f633b224c1a/2014/11/0065B3.png` ?

Thank you :-)

Comment: `strtok` or a regex would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation the following should do it?

```
$clean = substr($img_url, 0, strpos($img_url, '.png|')+4);
```

`$img_url` would be the url.

This obviously is only good if there's no possibility of `.png|` appearing anywhere else in the url

**UPDATE:**

Or this for any file extension

`$clean = preg_replace('/\|.*+/','',$url);`

Comment: If the extension varies between gif, jpg, png, how would I do this? Thank you

Comment: @michaelmcgurk you should have mentioned that in your question as answers depend on the information provided. In the case of different file extensions, my answer is no good. You'll want to use one of the regex options.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk see the update, that should work for any extension for the corrupt urls in the format you've provided